# Finding directories with a certain regex

Tags: regex, powershell

I think the regex is right for powershell, but I think my logic is wrong.

What I want to do is get a list of all the directories that start with 4-to-6 digits. What I get so far is the child items in directories that start with 4-6 digits:

```
get-childitem -path \\server\share -recurse | 
where { ($_.psiscontainer) -and ($_.name -match "^\d{4,6}") }
```

Can I somehow pipe into a write for 'current object' rather than child?

Comment: change your regex to `"^\d{4,6}"`

Comment: Instead of `($_.psiscontainer)` you could use the `-Directory` switch of `Get-ChildItem` as long as you have at least v3 of PS

Comment: @Avinash-Raj yes there is a ^ but again the problem is that I'm getting the child items in that directory back, not the directory itself.

Comment: If it was *nix I would supgest `ls -p -R  | grep -oP '^\d{4,6}(?=/$)'`

Comment: The code you posted should do exactly what you're asking. Please provide evidence.

Comment: Sorry; my previous regex is ignoring some of the constraint like the "starting with" part. `ls -p -R |'(^|.*/)\d{1,2}.*(?=/$)'`

Comment: @JJoao The question is about PowerShell (i.e. Windows). Advice about Linux shells is not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I just piped into | ft, making the total command:

```
get-childitem -path \\path\path -recurse | where {($_.psiscontainer) 
-and ($_.name -match "^\d{4,6}" )} | Select-Object Name, FullName | ft
```